# Send application request to user's friend using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to send my application request to user's friends using Graph API, is there any way to do this please help me I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for a person to request somebody to be their friend is through the Facebook web interface.You can request for the user only not his friends.